# Redirecting in ASP.NET MVC using Javascript or something else the best way?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect

I have a confirm box and redirect to an action but it is not working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  function quitProgram()
    {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to quit your current program?");
        if (answer)
            window.location("http://www.google.com");
        else
            window.location("http://www.yahoo.com");
     }
    </script>
```

Html Code -

```
<input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Quit Program" id="QuitProgram" onclick="quitProgram()" />
```

But the redirect never happens...can anyone help me with this..ultimately what i want to do is redirect to an action based on user response...it would be great if anyone lets me know the best way i should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuart [identified one problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196904/redirecting-in-asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-or-something-else-the-best-way/3196916#3196916) with the code posted in the question. One more thing you'll have to do is change the `input` element's type from "submit" to "button", or the submit will cause a post that will override the redirect.

Answer (score 4):

window.location is a property not a method:

```
if (answer)
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
else
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

Comment: Nice.. it's like a brain teaser sometimes, when something looks right but is the totally wrong syntax.

Comment: ya...my bad...and thanks Jeff...actually that submit was a  problem..it worked when i changed it to button..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this

```
function quitProgram()
{
    var answer = return confirm("Are you sure you want to quit your current program?");
    if (answer)
        window.location("http://www.google.com");
    else
        window.location("http://www.yahoo.com");
 }
```